# Style same type of element throughout document

Tags: lists, italic

I am new to Latex and am wondering if there exists anything like a `class` in HTML. I have been writing a bunch of documents lately and all my `\item`s have needed to be *italized*, is there some way to indicate at the beginning of the file how to style `\item`s without have to do:

```
\item \texit{.........................} 
\item \texit{.........................} 
\item \texit{.........................} 
\item \texit{.........................} 
\item \texit{.........................} 
\item \texit{.........................}
```

over and over again?

Comment: There is nothing like a class in HTML, since there is no DOM.  But there are ways to customize list environments to italicize the body of each list item.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks, I was just trying to find a good analogous example. Could you point me to the package or an example of customizing list items ?

Comment: the `enumitem` package is pretty handy for lists

Comment: Oh! and [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @SeanAllred Thanks, I just looked at the docs for that package, seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry for my nonconstructive comment yesterday.  I knew that others would fill in answers, and I didn't have time to do my own until today.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang No worries. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the behaviour of the itemize environment directly, exploiting the fact that `\begin{itemize}` calls the macro `\itemize` within a `\begingroup ... \endgroup` pair.

### Example code

```
\setlength\parindent{0ex}
\let\originalitemize\itemize

\def\itemize{\originalitemize\itshape}
Some text
\begin{itemize}
\item foo \emph{(bar)} \item bar
\end{itemize}
Some text
\def\itemize{\originalitemize\scshape}
\begin{itemize}
\item foo \emph{(bar)} \item bar
\end{itemize}
Some text
```

In the above code, we use `\let\originalitemize\itemize` to save the meaning of the original `\itemize` macro, to allow us to make use of the original meaning when we customize the behaviour of `itemize` environments. This example shows two overriding customizations with different typefaces.

### Result

[image: Result of sample code]

Note that because the typeface which we declare for `\itemize` is contained within a `\begingroup ... \endgroup` pair, the change in typeface doesn't extend any further than the environment. (This also incidentially demonstrates how you can obtain blocks of non-italicized text, or more accurately, how to toggle between italicized and non-italicized text.)

Comment: Does this also put the labels in `\scshape`?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: I'm not sure what you mean. The second example of restyling `itemize` certainly does, or do you mean item labels if you make an `\item[label]`? (It does, if that's what you're asking; if one wanted to prevent this behaviour, one could also redefine `\itemize` so that it modifies the `\item` command.)

Comment: I was asking if the second example puts the bullets in `\scshape` font.  It seems to be true.  Not that it's noticeable in this question, but if you wanted to, say, change the color of the item body, this method would also change the color of the bullets.

Answer (score 2):

Niel's answer is a good one for what you want to do.  I was thinking more generally of the question: how to change the formatting of the body of an `enumerate` or `itemize` environment, *without changing the item labels*?

In order to do this, you have to switch the font commands on and off after each `\item` and before the next `\item`.  The trouble is that `\item` takes an optional argument.  So to make it work, patch the auxiliary macro `\@item`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\setlength\parindent{0ex}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@item}{\normalfont\normalcolor}
{\message{Patching of @item succeeded.}}
{\message{Patching of @item failed.}}
\apptocmd{\@item}{\scshape\color{red}}
{\message{Patching of @item succeeded.}}
{\message{Patching of @item failed.}}

\makeatother


\begin{itemize}
\item foo \emph{(bar)} \item bar
\end{itemize}
Some text

\begin{enumerate}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

So when TeX encounters `\@item`, it will:

1. switch the font and color (back) to `\normal`
2. do what `\@item` would normally do, which is to set a label and change the margins, etc.
3. switch the font to `\scshape` and color to `red`.

Here is the output:

[image: sample code output]

Answer (score 1):

What about `\def\ititemize{\begin{itemize}\itshape}`?

Comment: This works, but makes everything in the item italicized, I have blocks of text after the `\item` that I would like to keep normal, is there any way to do that ?

Comment: `\textrm{your block}`. But I don't know the percentage of normal text.